# Pentaho Data Integration 8.2 - Timestamp blank on Excel Writer

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a table input step pulling data from Informix datawarehouse and one of the columns (DLV_TM) is in DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE.

I added a Select Values Step after and formatted to column to Timestamp with h:mm:ss format.

In the Excel Writer content tab, the column has a Timestamp type and h:mm:ss format.

The transformation runs successfully and the preview data even shows the correct time format but when I open the excel file, the column is blank.

Please help!

Comment: Please provide your transformation , so that we can look in to this.

Comment: problem with your office version. according to your office select the version in pdi and try.